# How can I click button without an ID?

Tags: html, vb.net

I'm trying click this text button with `InvokeMember("click")` in VB.NET:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("button").InvokeMember("click")
```

This gives the following error message:

> object didnt find

How I can do this? What is the button ID?

```
<div jscontroller="cUYNmd" jsaction="click:KjsqPd(preventDefault=true);rcuQ6b:WYd;Z2AmMb:GZxqQe;RdYeUb:kv7bJd;" jsname="bCkDte" class="IMH1vc lUHSR Hj2jlf" tabindex="0" role="link">Şifrenizi mi unuttunuz?</div>
```

Comment: Your `div` doesn't *have* an `id` value.  Did you mean to give it one?

Comment: no, i m doing one proje, it s have to click that button but button doesnt have an id.

Comment: "object didnt find" doesn't look like a real error message. In the future, please make sure to _copy and paste error messages **exactly**_.

Comment: you need to find some other way to uniquely identify it. It has a number of CSS classes you could potentially use, depending if this makes a unique combination within the document or not. Or perhaps the other attributes, or some combination of them. Or perhaps if you know its position in the DOM, you can navigate to some known element which contains it, and then narrow your search for buttons to be within that element.

Comment: The object reference is not set to the instance of an object.

Comment: İ m try use to gmail "i did forget password" service for sms. İ can write mail and next step but now i couldnt click

Comment: oke problem solved. i find recovery password page :) i dont have to click now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$("button[jscontroller='cUYNmd']").InvokeMember("click");`
Use which ever attribute you want to use in place of jscontroller. If it is a `div` type div instead of button there.